# Will RemoteApp users have VNET IP if RemoteApp is set up within our Azure VNET?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, remoteapp

If we deploy RemoteApp within our VNET on Azure, when users go out to the Internet, will they all have an IP address from our Azure VNET?

I'm trying to understand if accessing the Internet from RemoteApp is like accessing the Internet from a corporate network with a firewall where all users would have the public IP of the firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the source IP address of the traffic leaving the remoteApp collection will be the VNET address space if your deploy the RemoteApp in the Virtual Network ( you have to choose a specific subnet )

Answer (score 0):

Any traffic going to he Internet from Azure VMs will use the source IP address as its VIP (Virtual IP address), which is a public IPv4 address.